# Finite fields of order 8 and isomorphism

Tags: finite-fields

Given the following finite fields,
$$F_1=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{\langle x^3+x+1\rangle}$$ and $$F_2=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle},$$
I know that they are isomorphic because their orders are both equal $8$. How can I find an isomorphism between them?

We can write 
$$F_1=\left\{c_0+c_1 \alpha + c_2 \alpha^2 : \alpha^3=-\alpha-1,\; c_0,c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \right\}$$
and
$$F_2=\left\{c_0+c_1 \alpha + c_2 \alpha^2 : \alpha^3=-\alpha^2-1,\; c_0,c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \right\},$$
still I have no idea how to go ahead.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Proper notation is $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{\langle x^3+x+1\rangle},$ not $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{<x^3+x+1>}.$ I edited accordingly. If you don't know things like this, then google "latex symbols" and you'll find it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The ideal generated by $x^3+x+1$ is often also written as $(x^3+x+1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe I've seen that notation. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d f_i x^i$ is irreducible over a field $F$, then its reversal $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d f_{d-i} x^i$ is also irreducible and defines an isomorphic field.

In your case, $x^3+x+1$ and $x^3+x^2+1$ are reversals.

To see this, let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$, so $f(\alpha)=0$. Let $\beta = \tfrac1\alpha$, then $$0=f(\alpha)=f(\tfrac 1 \beta) = \sum_{i=0}^d f_i \beta^{-i} = \beta^{-d} \sum_{i=0}^d f_i \beta^{d-i} = \beta^{-d} g(\beta)$$ and so $\beta$ is a root of $g$.

Comment: But note that this takes advantage of the special shape of your polynomials. If they didn't have this property, you would have to show there is an isomorphism more directly.

Comment: Right you are, @Doris. In my experience, it may require special techniques or arguments to find an isomorphism between two fields of the same cardinality (but experts may have techniques that I  don’t know).

Answer (score 2):

The zeros of $x^3+x^2+1$ are the reciprocals of the zeros of $x^3+x+1$.

Better: write $F_2=\{c_0+c_1\beta+c^2\beta^2:\cdots\}$.
We can map $\alpha\in F_1$ to $1/\beta=\beta^2+\beta\in F_2$.

Comment: Wow! Really thanks. It works. Does it work in general for every finite group?